# Jquery effect not working

Tags: jquery, html

Playing with jquery effects.

I click on .div2 and nothing happens.  Can't figure it out.  Probably something very simple.  The only css I have sets the width of the div.  Nothing else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JQ Effects</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="JQ_animation.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".div2").click(function () {
                    $(".div2").slideDown(3000);

                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            <div class="div2">Menu</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're sliding div2 down (which is already visible) after you click on div2. I don't understand that. You may want to post the content of `JQ_animation.css`

Comment: `slideDown` is a way to make a hidden element visible. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: ahhh.  There it is.  Sorry, newbie mistake.  Thanks. @j08691 you too.

Answer (score 0):

You called same div 2 time. there there nothing to slidedown .slidedown work for slide /visible hidden item.I assume you want to show your menu as slide down . here is a example how to do it.You can change it to your own ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
});
});
</script>
<style> 
#panel, #flip {
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #e5eecc;
border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
padding: 50px;
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

slideDown() works on elements hidden with jQuery methods and display:none in CSS.

Here you did not hide the .div2 in anyway and you are trying to slide down which is not hidden.
Try something like this.When initially pressed the Menu wil get hidden and try to press on the same place you would get the slide down effect.

And by the this is not a good practice of making divs slide down by pressing on them. Instead create a button and make the button execute the onclick function rather than on the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JQ Effects</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="JQ_animation.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".div2").click(function () {
                    $(".div2").slideUp(3000);

                });
        $(".div2").click(function () {
                    $(".div2").slideDown(3000);

                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div1">
            <div class="div2">Menu</div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```